# Mix .L and .R files into a stereo file using SOX in bulk

Tags: audio, merge, bulk, sox

I have a folder full of WAV files with separate L and R channels. I've been using SOX for some things like changing the sample rate of the audio files inside a specific folder using this code:

```
for file in *.wav; do sox $file -r 44100 -b 24 converted/$(basename $file) -V; done
```

For example, I have these two files that I want to merge: 
 - CLOSE_1_02.L.wav
 - CLOSE_1_02.R.wav
I would like to merge them in a stereo file (L in the left channel and R in the right channel) with the name: "CLOSE_1_02.wav". Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry, but the answer (1) is wrong. The questioner wants a two-channel file with one sound file in the left channel, and the other in the right channel. I tried the command given, and it produces a 1-channel output.wav with both input files mixed into a single channel.

Comment: I confirmed this : if you are trying to merge 2 GSM mono files, the output will be a GSM file mono.

Answer (score 1):

from [link](https://www.nesono.com/node/275):

```
sox -M input.l.wav input.r.wav output.wav
```

will merge input.l.wav and input.r.wav into output.wav. As others have noted, the result will be a mono file.

Comment: This will generate a mono file as @user60381 noticed