# I need some slightly basic BASH help - find + execdir + sox

Tags: bash, shell, audio, mono, sox

Ok, hello. I have some scripts that I use on the command line to rip mp3s from .wav and .aif files. Lately I've been playing with this sampler that wants only mono wav files. WAIT - I promise this is a programming question.
I want to run a command to split all wav files inside a directory to mono files with a different file name.
So, for example Drummerrolleasy.wav, would then have DrummerrolleasyL.wav in the same directory as the left mono split of the original stereo wav.
I will ensure that when the command runs, there are only stereo wav files in the directory.
I have this command:

```
find . -name "*.wav" -execdir echo $1    {} \;
```

that works as expected, and provides me the names of the files, one by one, that I would like to then put inside a call to sox.
[image: a sample run of the name list - yes I already added the L split files so really this shows what directory should look like AFTER execution]
this:

```
find . -type f -name “*.wav” -exec sox {} "$1" L"$1"  \;
```

does not work (runs but does nothing), and I'm not finding anything particularly illuminating for how to do this. I might need to spawn a new shell, but this doesn't work either because the shell just sits there:

```
find . -name "*.wav" -execdir sh -c 'sox "{}" "$1" “L””$1"’ \;
```

If I have to figure this out on my own, that can work too, and when I get there I will update but if someone would like to point me in the right direction I would be much obliged.

Comment: also, the direct call to sox looks like this: **sox Drummersurvive.wav DrummersurviveL.wav remix 1** - source name, copy name, remix and 1 for the LEFT channel.

Comment: nor does this work: **find . -type f -name “*.wav” -execdir sox  {} "$1" L"$1" remix 1  \;**

Answer (score 0):

Goes like this:

```
for file in *.wav; do sox $file L$file remix 1; done
```

thanks [Mix .L and .R files into a stereo file using SOX in bulk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397617/mix-l-and-r-files-into-a-stereo-file-using-sox-in-bulk/44753144#44753144)

saves me a lot of time. BASH rules.